# MYSQL - How to go about doing a join with subselect join

Tags: php, mysql

I am not sure how to word this so the question maybe look vague. I will try my best to describe the issue I am having.

I have a 3 tables:

```
LibraryRepairEvent
MemberBorrowsBook
Book
```

This is how LibraryRepairEvent looks like:

[image: LibraryRepairEvent]

This is how MemberBorrowsBook looks like:

[image: MemberBorrowsBook]

This is how Book looks like:

[image: Book]

What I am trying to do is out of all the events there, I want to find the organiser who raised the most donations and fetch some information in regards from the Book Table.

This is what I have so far :

```
SELECT *
FROM Book bk
JOIN (SELECT b.bookID, SUM(lre.donationsCollected) as maxDonations
FROM Book b
    JOIN MemberBorrowsBook mbb
            ON b.bookID = mbb.bookID
    LEFT JOIN LibraryRepairEvent lre 
            ON mbb.memberID = lre.organiserID
) a
ON bk.bookID = a.bookID
GROUP BY maxDonations
ORDER BY maxDonations DESC
```

However this query does not work as how it should be. Based on the screenshots I have included. It's returning the wrong information back.

Based on the example, LibraryRepairEvent shows organiserId jessicaalba@gmail.com has the highest amount raised (tallying up the donations of 900). Now it will look at the MemberBorrowsBook  table by using the join on memberID to get the bookID. So here I will have 45441 and 45651 as the bookID which then will be taken to the Book table. So now the end result should have been the details of these ID's but I am getting wrong data back.

Please ask me if unsure of anything.

Comment: your `group by` looks wrong to me

Comment: What is the expected outcome?

Comment: Have I understood your question correctly? You want to find the books borrowed by the most "successful" event organiser? [A little strange requirement, isn't it?]

Comment: Yeah you are right

Comment: So the expected outcome is, it should find bookID 45441 and 45651. So information regarding these books should be the outcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do. Select your columns accordingly.
I set up a [rextester demo](http://rextester.com/ZSSU24707) here, it would have helped us a lot if you had done so yourself. Perhaps next time :-)

```
select * from 
(
   select OrganiserID, sum(DonationsCollected) totalDonations from LibraryRepairEvent group by OrganiserID
) summary
join MemberBorrowsBook mbb on mbb.MemberID = summary.OrganiserID
join Book b on mbb.BookID = b.BookID
where totalDonations = (
    select max(totalDonations) from 
    (
        select sum(DonationsCollected) totalDonations from LibraryRepairEvent group by OrganiserID
    ) summary2
)
;
```

**NOTE** This statement returns the information related to all rank-1 organisers. So if there are more than one achieving the highest donation sum, all of them will be reported. If you only want one of them this statement can be simplified significantly.